# Build wget with GnuTLS?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, wget

I am having trouble getting `wget` to build. Here are my current incantations, trimmed for brevity

```
host=i686-w64-mingw32
prefix=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw

# Install gmp
./configure --host=$host --prefix=$prefix
make install

# Install nettle
./configure --host=$host --prefix=$prefix
make install AR=$host-ar

# Install GnuTLS
./configure --host=$host --prefix=$prefix --disable-shared
make install

# Install Wget
./configure --host=$host --prefix=$prefix --disable-ipv6
make install
```

The error is on the final `make install` with `wget`

```
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/libgnutls.a(base64.o): In function `base64_encode':
/home/Steven/gnutls-3.0.19/gl/base64.c:69: multiple definition of `_base64_encode'
utils.o:utils.c:(.text+0x49b0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You probably have some old object code lying around. Do a `make clean` and delete any *.o files you see, then try again. Also, you don't say which of the 4 compilations above is the one that failed with that error (going by the error, I'm assuming GnuTLS - which means wget has nothing to do with this question).

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `multiple definition` error is happening because `base64_encode` is defined more than once.

```
// wget-1.13.4/src/utils.c
int
base64_encode (const void *data, int length, char *dest)

// gnutls-3.0.19/gl/base64.c
void
base64_encode (const char *restrict in, size_t inlen,
               char *restrict out, size_t outlen)
```

This problem was introduced with GnuTLS 3.0.13. Using version 3.0.12 solved the problem for me.

[`ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnutls`](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnutls)